# Looping through an Array in Javascript from a PHP Array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, alert

I have an Array in a PHP variable called: $TillArray

I want to pass this value to a Javascript function and display an Alert for each item in the array.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ArrayFunction(<?= $TillArray ?>);
</script>
```

Here is the function code:

```
function ArrayFunction(MyArray)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) 
    {
        alert(MyArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The function displays an "Undefined" message.

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't do that. You'd have to make the array loopable by JS by turning it into an array that JS can use. You could turn it into JSON, but that depends on how you created the array. If all indexes were numerical, `json_encode` will turn it into a JS array and any of the 3 basic loops could iterate over it. But if its an associative array, it will turn it into a JS object and you will have to use the `for-in` loop.

```
ArrayFunction(<?= json_encode($TillArray) ?>);
```